# SWI Prolog: Ask for consulted files

Tags: swi-prolog

Is there a way in SWI Prolog to ask for consulted files?
For example, I consulted two files with:

```
consult('load.pl').

consult('main.pl').
```

Now I need a predicate that give me all consulted files, because I want to check, if they are already loaded or not. At the moment, I'm building a gui for consulting files and I don't want that the user have to add one, if it is not necessary.

Comment: Maybe you just want to implement something like `make/0`?

Answer (score 1):

The predicate you need is the built-in [`source_file/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=source_file/1), documented [together with `consult/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=consulting). You can also look at `source_file/2` on the same page.

Note that depending on the libraries you are using in your code you will get a list of many files you did not consult directly.

Anyway, if you want to only load if not loaded yet, you should also look into [`ensure_loaded/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ensure_loaded/1) documented on the same page.

Comment: `ensure_loaded/1` does not check dates in SWI - so it cannot be used to reload a file. In SICStus and YAP it can be used to this end.